# How to use xpath in my test cases?

Tags: java, appium, selendroid

1. I have the below defined xpath. How can I use this xpath in my test  cases -

   ```
   android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[2]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.TextView[1]
   ```
2. How can I use this xpath in my program?
3. I have tried with below xpath element, but it doesn't work at all -

   ```
   driver.findElement(by.xpath("android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.Frame‌Layout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneL‌​ayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[2]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/androi‌​d.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.Relative‌​Layout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.TextView[1]").click();
   ```

Comment: have you tried anything , show us xpath you tried

Comment: @sanojlawrence, I have tried with driver.findElement(by.xpath("android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[2]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.TextView[1]").click();

Comment: Post this in you question only then others can help you

Comment: what's the error you are getting??

Comment: @Gaurav, It shows xpath can't be found.

Comment: yea, so that means xpath is wrong. This is nothing wrong with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.Frame‌Layout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneL‌​ayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[2]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/androi‌​d.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.Relative‌​Layout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.TextView[1]").click();
```